# how do I chage pixel color? (SDL2)

Tags: c++, sdl2, pixel

After a long time away, I'm coming back to SDL, using version SDL2.
I have some example code that does pretty much exactly what I want it to do, but I want to change the pixel color. Ive tried changing the function of *pixels, to make pixels a surface where I might have the option to change color, but I cant seem to figure out how to change the color.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
//Source: https://bitbucket.org/dandago/gigilabs/src/master/Sdl2PixelDrawing/Sdl2PixelDrawing/main.cpp
//Define window height, width
#define height 1280
#define width   760
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    bool leftMouseButtonDown = false;
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Pixel Drawing",  SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, height, width, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

    SDL_Renderer * renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_Texture * texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,  SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, height, width);
    Uint32 * pixels = new Uint32[height * width];
 
//SDL_Surface* pixels = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat(0, width, height,32, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBX8888);

 
    memset(pixels, 255, height * width * sizeof(Uint32)); //int is bg color

    while (!quit){
        SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, pixels, height * sizeof(Uint32));
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);

        switch (event.type){
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                    leftMouseButtonDown = true;
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                    leftMouseButtonDown = true;
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                if (leftMouseButtonDown){
                    int mouseX = event.motion.x;
                    int mouseY = event.motion.y;
                    
                    pixels[mouseY * height+ mouseX] = 0;
                     }
                break;
        }
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    delete[] pixels;
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean this `pixels[mouseY * height+ mouseX] = 0;` pixel color? Choose a value other than `0` then.

Comment: I tried that, a whole range of numbers between 0-255. .. oh wait pixels is uint32, snap, I might not have noticed a difference at that scale.

Comment: FFFF--... Thanks, that was it.

Comment: `oh wait pixels is uint32` Yeah, its `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888` which means alpha byte, red byte, green byte and blue byte, stuffed together in an `uint32`. Might be reversed though due to little endian.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, be sure to post your solution as an answer below.